# How do I listen for event in a more actionscript-friendly way?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a flex application where the child dispatches an event inside a parent:

child:

```
<fx:Metadata>
[Event(name="myEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent")); 
]]>
</fx:Script>
```

parent:

```
<comp:poppy id="myPopup" myEvent="myEventStuff(event);" />
```

I've changed my code so that I create myChild in actionscript, rather than the mxml tag as shown. How do I add the event listener in actionscript?

```
public function showPoppy(evt:MouseEvent):void {

var myPopup:poppy = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, poppy, true) as poppy;

PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myPopup:poppy );
myPopup:poppy.includeInLayout = true;
myPopup:poppy.visible = true;

// how do I add the event listener?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is break out the "myEvent" string in your poppy class to a static String within the poppy class:

```
public static const MY_EVENT:String = "myEvent";
```

Then, your ActionScript component can listen for this event from your "myPopup" instance:

```
myPopup.addEventListener(poppy.MY_EVENT, handleMyEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

And just a detail, you shouldn't put some bare code in . Prefer something like that:

```
<s:Group ... creationComplete="onCreationComplete">
<fx:Metadata>
[Event(name="myEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private function onCreationComplete(e:Event):void
{
  dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent")); 
}
]]>
</fx:Script>
```